# Do action on time specify in database

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have asp.net app which save users request to send mail on exact time to seconds. I save this data in Sql Server.

How can I check table for this records and handle send e-mail on time save in db, that app themselves check for new data and know that : now I must send email.

Any idea?

Comment: create `Boolean` column `IsDelivered` that check mail sent or not.. next time fetch those entries which have not been sent from the last mail sent time to now as per their `mail sent time`

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You have to create scheduled job checking conditions and send email. Don't forget to mark row as *email sent*.

Answer (score 0):

If your email contents(that you want to sent to the customer) is also stored in the database & you want SQL Server to send emails to the customers, you need to [create SQL job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx) for that:

Comment: SQL job can invoke .net method which send this email ?

Comment: Of course : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136818/reference-net-assembly-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-or-function